# 3des for arduino uno

Tags: arduino, 3des

I am working with Arduino Uno board, and I want to reuse 3DES from one open source, I have known that libnfc and libfreefare having those functions but those cannot be extracted to run on Arduino. Does anyone knows where I can find the library that works for Arduino Uno?

Answer (score 0):

ArduinoDES should be good choice - you have options for DES and triple DES:
http://spaniakos.github.io/ArduinoDES/